# How do I figure out in which state is NYC?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to properly query dbpedia and figure out the US State of New York City.
I wrote the below query that returns the information among other things, but I am unsure how to change my query so it returns only the New York State.

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
 values ?city { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> }
 
        ?city dbo:subdivision ?subdivision
 
}
```

[result](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20values%20%3Fcity%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNew_York_City%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20dbo%3Asubdivision%20%3Fsubdivision%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

Comment: you can get all direct relations between both with `select * {
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_(state)> ?p  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> 
} UNION {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> ?p  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_(state)>
}
}` - I doubt that subdivision property is helpful here#

Comment: I want the State to be the result of the query, without knowing it in advance. Therefore it can't be part of the query.

Comment: that I understood ... my query just indicates that there is no meaningful relation in DBpedia which exclusively maps a US city to its US state, as you can also see from the result of your query. I mean, obviously `subdivision`is used to map to districts but also to the state New York City is contained in. SPARQL doesn't do magic, if the data isn't "good" enough, we're usually lost.

Comment: all you can try to do is to make same constraints on the division, e.g. `SELECT *
WHERE
{
 values ?city { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> }
 
        ?city dbo:subdivision ?subdivision . ?subdivision dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:States_of_the_United_States>
 
}` - **but**, you will not have any guarantee that for other cities in DBpedia there is such a `dbo:division` fact.